# How can I assign players randomly to a team but ensuring the teams keep a roughly equal size?

Tags: python, random, chatbot, tortoise-orm

So I am working on a twitch bot where people in chat will execute the command `!play` which if not already in a clan will assign them to one a number of clans (probably four) but could increase.

The bit where I'm stuck is how I will assign each player to a random team but also keep the teams as even as possible in numbers to ensure fair competition and not sure how I go about it.

Once idea which a friend came up with was to use `random.shuffle` to shuffle a list of clans and assign each player in order until the end of the list and then reshuffle and start again, which sounds good on paper but not sure how to implement that in an async environment  as anytime someone types `!play` it will execute independently of each other.

The clans and players are to be stored into a db using tortoise-orm:

This is the models for reference:

```py
from tortoise.models import Model
from tortoise import fields

class Clan(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=255)
    tag = fields.CharField(max_length=255)


class Player(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    clan = fields.ForeignKeyField('models.Clan', related_name='players')
```

The code so far for my `!play` command:

```py
class BomCommandsCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Cog) -> None:
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx: commands.Context) -> None:
        """
        !play command
        """

        if Clan.all().annotate(Count("id")) == 0:
            await ctx.send("No clans have been created yet.")
        else:
            if Player.filter(name=ctx.author.name).exists():
                await ctx.send("You have already joined a clan.")
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: Assign the new member to the clan with the lowest number of members (or if two or more clans are tied for lowest, a random choice among those clans.)  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

I was definitely over complicating this, and thanks to the comment by John, I have fixed this with the below code, which will make a list of clan(s) with the lowest values and make a random choice from one of them.

```py
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx: commands.Context) -> None:
    """
    !play command
    """

    if await Clan.all().count() == 0:
        await ctx.send("No clans have been created yet.")
    else:
        if await Player.filter(name=ctx.author.name).exists():
            await ctx.send("You have already joined a clan.")
        else:
            clan_totals = await Clan.all().annotate(count=Count("players", distinct=True)).values("id", "name", "tag", "count")
            min_total = min(clan_totals, key=lambda x:x["count"])
            clans_to_choose_from = [clan["id"] for clan in clan_totals if clan["count"] == min_total["count"]]
            new_clan = random.choice(clans_to_choose_from)
            await Player.create(name=ctx.author.name, clan_id=new_clan)
            clan_details = next(clan for clan in clan_totals if clan["id"] == new_clan)
            await ctx.send(f"Welcome @{ctx.author.name} to the [{clan_details['tag']}] {clan_details['name']} Clan roster!")
```